# ask about advance search when user select all something?

Tags: php, html, mysql

ask about advance search when user select all something ?

my form have 2 drop-down and 1 submit button

```
        ________________                ________________
body : |______All_______|      color : |______All_______|
       |____Circle______|              |_____White______|
       |___Triangle_____|              |_____Black______|

         __________
        |__Submit__|
```

And this is my database : Draw

```
 _________________________________   
|__id___|____Body____|___Corlor___|
|___1___|___Circle___|___White____|
|___2___|__Triangle__|___Black____|
|___3___|__Triangle__|___Black____|
|___4___|___Circle___|___White____|
|___5___|__Triangle__|___Black____|
|___6___|___Circle___|___White____|
|___7___|___Circle___|___White____|
|___8___|__Triangle__|___Black____|
```

And this is my php code for select data from Mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Draw WHERE Body = '$_POST[body]' AND Color = '$_POST[color]' order by id asc";
```

OK, When i select drop-down body -----> All and drop-down color ------> All

value of `$_POST[body]` = "All" And `$_POST[color]` = "All"
, And i run page it will not get any data from my sql

How to select data from mysql table : Draw, When i select drop-down with All value ?

Thank for ans ^^

Comment: For such a tiny data set, I'd just return the entire data set and do all the filtering with javascript. E.g. http://jsfiddle.net/SdUQ5/

Comment: You'll need some logic to rewrite that query when `$_POST["body"]=="all"` and remove the `Body =...` clause (same for color). Also, this is vulnerable to SQL injection as written - use parameterized queries to avoid this.

Comment: Strawberry --- this demo are best thank .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case your query fetches all entries with body and color set to 'All'.
You get no data because there are no entries for that values.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$query       = "SELECT * FROM Draw";
$where       = "";

if(isset($_POST["body"]) && $_POST["body"] != "") {
    if($_POST["body"] != "All") {
        $where .= "`Body`='" . $_POST["body"] . "'";
    }
}

if(isset($_POST["color"]) && $_POST["color"] != "") {
    if($_POST["body"] != "All") {
        if ($where.length() > 0) {
            $where .= " AND ";
        }
        $where .= "`Color`='" . $_POST["color"] . "'";
    }
}

if ($where.length() > 0) {
    $query .= " WHERE " . $where;
}
```

Additionally you should read up on SQL injections.

Comment: Why are you quoting `body` and `color`? I think you meant to put `

Answer (score 0):

You code is pretty dangerous and vulnerable to injection.

If you are using mysql_query() then shift to `mysqli` or `PDO.`

Below is the code snippet with the logic for your case.

NOTE:: I am assuming you are using `mysqli_*`

```
$con = // Your mysqli connection ;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Draw WHERE 1=1 "; 
$where = "";
if(isset($_POST["body"]) && $_POST["body"] != ''){
    if(trim($_POST["body"]) != "All"){
            $where .= " AND `Body` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["body"])."'" ;
    }
}
if(isset($_POST["color"]) && $_POST["color"] !=''){
    if(trim($_POST["color"]) != "All"){
            $where .= " AND `Color` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["color"])."'" ;
    }
}

$sql .= $where ;

execute $sql ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to make the query in parts.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM Draw ";

if($_POST['body']!='All'){$where[1]='Body = "'.$_POST['body'].'"';}
if($_POST['color']!='All'){$where[2]='Color = "'.$_POST['color'].'"';}

if(count($where>0)){
    $where=' WHERE '.implode(' AND ',$where);
   }

$query.=$where;
```

Comment: You might end up with two `WHERE` in your query if both body and color are not equal to All

Comment: Hahaha, you're right, will change it. Didn't notice it.